# How to tell someone you will do something in a near future? (For example: in a minute)

Tags: grammar

When some one ask me questions like:
- Are you not going school?
- Are you not leaving?
In a case when I'm about to do that thing. I usually say "in a minute".
Are there any other alternatives?

Thank you

Comment: "*consider it done*"

Comment: I'll get to that in a minute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"I'm about to" usually works well. It shows that you are going to do it very soon.